# Dispatch_queue issue

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios5, grand-central-dispatch

I'm new using `dispatch_queue_t` and I have two problems with my app which I think that could be solved using GCD. The first one is that in the main view (ViewController) I have a label which is actualized by another class (AudioViewController), and when I do any user interaction in ViewController the label stop to actualize, so I think if I use `dispatch_queue_t` this problem will be solved.

The second thing is that in the same main view (ViewController) when I press a contribution I call another class (ContributionViewController) and this class accesses just a instance variable of another class (AudioViewController) which is refreshed all the time. When I start contribution, I made a loop to get more than one value to make some calculus with them and those values are all the same though.

I'll put some code here trying to clear the things.

`ViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)makeContribution:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"A: Contribution button clicked");
  NSLog(@"-= START CONTRIBUTION =-");
  cvc = [[ContributionViewController alloc] init];
  cvc.avc = self.avc;

  // Get NUM_CONTRIBUTIONS contributions to make average.
  int contContribution;
  for (contContribution = 0; contContribution < NUM_CONTRIBUTIONS; contContribution++) {
        [cvc getEachContribution];
  }

  // Make average
  [cvc makeAverage:NUM_CONTRIBUTIONS];

  [cvc release];
}
```

`AudioViewController.m`

```
- (void)audioInitializationWithTimeInterval:(float)time
{
   NSDictionary* recorderSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM],AVFormatIDKey,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:44100],AVSampleRateKey,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                                  nil];
   NSError* error;

   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];
   recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recorderSettings error:&error];

   //enable measuring
   //tell the recorder to start recording:
   [recorder record];

   if (recorder) {
      [recorder prepareToRecord];
      recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
      [recorder record];

      levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time target:self selector:@selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
   }
   else
      NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
}


- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer
{

   //NSLog(@"-= AVC =-");
   [recorder updateMeters];

   db = [recorder averagePowerForChannel:0] - DBOFFSET;
   db += 120;
   db = db < 0 ? 0 : db;

   vc.lab_decibel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", db];
}
```

`ContributionViewController.m`

```
- (void)getEachContribution
{
  actualContribution = self.avc.db;
  NSLog(@"Actual contribution: %f", actualContribution);
  NSLog(@"Sum before: %0.2f", sumContribution);
  sumContribution += actualContribution;
  NSLog(@"Sum After: %0.2f", sumContribution);
}


- (void)makeAverage:(int)numOfContributions
{
  self.average = self.sumContribution / numOfContributions;
  NSLog(@"Average: %0.2f", self.average);
}
```

So, the main thing is `dispatch_queue_t` is going to solve my problems and how to do that? I've tried to put `dispatch_queue_t` on AudioViewController, ContributionViewController and ViewController, but the first didn't update the label, the second crashed and the third one the label still with 0 value.

Thanks for any tips to solve this problem.

EDIT 01:
[image: ViewController with mapView, decibel label and Contribution button]

The decibel label changes all the time.

Comment: This makes no sense. [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) is not the right tool for coordinating between [view controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457). It's for letting a view controller to initiate some time consuming action in the background. And the logic in `makeContribution` suggests we're not even really talking about view controllers. This makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe if you step back and alter your question and tell us what views you anticipate having, what you want the user to be able to do in those views (from that we can figure out what your view controllers should be) and then tell us what you're trying to do functionally, maybe we can offer better insights. From that, we can get into what the appropriate technologies (GCD vs simple view controller properties and methods) make sense.

Comment: Well, my ViewController (vc) has a mapView with a label (to show dB value) and a button to make the contribution. My AudioViewController (avc) just update the label on ViewController basically and, in ContributeViewController (cvc) I try to get some dB values from AudioViewController, make some calculus and so on. All this things work fine.
There are two problem that I've already said before, the first one is when I, for example, zoom in/out mapView, the label stop to refresh, and when I stop to zooming it starts to refresh again. This is because I have only one thread.

Comment: The second thing is almost the same. When I press contribution button tha App stop to refresh the label, or to collect dB values in AudioViewController, and I can collect one single value I'd like to avc still refreshing for I collect different values of dB to make my calculous. And I think it happens because I have only one thread.
Did you understand now what I wanna do?
Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is starting to make sense. I didn't understand the mapView, contribution, etc. language. It was entirely cryptic, but I think I'm starting to understand your question. As I understand it, your question is why your user interface is not being updated. Ok, the big answer to your question is that you don't need GCD if you don't want to. The `NSTimer` does what you need.

Now, you say that your continuously updated db field is no longer updated. There's absolutely no reason why it shouldn't continue. I've tried it, and it works fine. There's something going on there. Personally, when I've got a NSTimer that is updating my UI, I make sure to turn it off in `viewDidDisappear` (no point in updating your UI if it's not visible) and always turn it on in `viewDidAppear`. When I did this, whenever I returned to my main view with the db numbers, it happily resumed. Or if I wanted another view controller to get the notifications, I just turned it back on using a delegate.

That might look like the following.

First, you probably want a delegate protocol:

```
//  DecibelNotifierDelegate.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol DecibelNotifierDelegate <NSObject>

@required

- (void)decibelNotifierUpdate:(CGFloat)db;

@end
```

And then, you want to define your DecibelNotifier class:

```
//  DecibelNotifier.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DecibelNotifierDelegate.h"

@interface DecibelNotifier : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<DecibelNotifierDelegate> delegate;
@property CGFloat db;

- (void)startWithInterval:(float)time target:(id<DecibelNotifierDelegate>)delegate;
- (void)stop;

@end
```

and

```
//  DecibelNotifier.m

#import "DecibelNotifier.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h"

@interface DecibelNotifier ()
{
    AVAudioRecorder *_recorder;
    NSTimer *_levelTimer;
}
@end

// note, your code makes reference to DBOFFSET and I don't know what that is. Update this following line accordingly.

#define DBOFFSET 0

@implementation DecibelNotifier

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize db = _db;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        NSDictionary* recorderSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM],AVFormatIDKey,
                                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:44100],AVSampleRateKey,
                                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                                          nil];
        NSError* error;

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];
        _recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recorderSettings error:&error];

        if (!_recorder)
            NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)startWithInterval:(float)time target:(id<DecibelNotifierDelegate>)delegate
{
    if (_recorder) 
    {
        self.delegate = delegate;

        [_recorder prepareToRecord];
        _recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [_recorder record];

        _levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time target:self selector:@selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (void)stop
{
    [_recorder stop];

    [_levelTimer invalidate];
    _levelTimer = nil;

    self.delegate = nil;
}

- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [_recorder updateMeters];

    CGFloat db = [_recorder averagePowerForChannel:0] - DBOFFSET;
    db += 120;
    db = db < 0 ? 0 : db;

    _db = db;

    [self.delegate decibelNotifierUpdate:db];
}

@end
```

So, the first view controller that wants the notifications might have a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) DecibelNotifier *dBNotifier;
```

You can initialize it with:

```
self.dBNotifier = [[DecibelNotifier alloc] init];
```

You can then turn on notifications with:

```
[self.dBNotifier startWithInterval:0.25 target:self];
```

So the question is when you turn these notifications on and off. I do it in `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`. You can also pass the dbNotifier to other view controllers and they can get notifications, too.

Like I said, I tried this out and it works fine, with any view controller that wants to get notifications can just turn it on and specify itself as the delegate, and you're off to the races.

Comment: Before I try this, just one remark because I think you didn't get yet. When I said: "your question is why your user interface is not being updated", actually it is updated, it just stop to update when I do something in the screen like, pinch, tap and so on, but when I stop to do this things then user interface come back to update normally. Now I'll try to do what you wrote above. Thanks one more time.

Comment: Then this code is unlikely to solve the problem. I thought you were trying to figure out how to get the updating dB figures on multiple view controllers (which this greatly simplifies). If your reader is freezing while you're still on the same window, then you will want to diagnose whether the problem is that the timer is failing, or whether the UI update is failing. Put a NSLog in your `levelTimerCallback` and figure out if the problem is (a) in the timer; (b) in the UI update; or (c) in the recorder.

Comment: Actually I think this problem is because my App has only one thread. I've tried to put another thread using <code>dispatch_queue_t</code> on AudioViewController in <code>levelTimerCallback</code> call, but didn't work. I also put in ViewController (<code>[cvc getEachContribution]</code> call) and the App crashed...

And I put NSLog in all places of my code, I just took them off to clean the code here.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'd be very surprised if it was a single thread problem. All of your UI updates should happen on a main thread thread anyway ... you can't do UI updates on the background threads. Is your NSTimer still running? And where is your app crashing and what is the message? If you're crashing, it suggests you have other problems. And I can't help without significantly more substantial code samples. But I put the recorder logic in a view controller, pushed to views controllers, had popovers, etc., and it always kept working. So it's got to be something else.